# C# ListViewに表示と中身を振り分ける方法

Tags: c#, windows

お世話になります。

コントロールのListViewにて、ListBoxでもできるような、
DisplayMemberとValueMemberに分けて、選択されたアイテムを
そのまま取り出したいのですが、そういう方法はありますでしょうか。

調べてみたところ、DataSourceを設定できないので無理なのかと思ったのですが、
他の方法でもかまいませんので、良い方法がありましたら教えてください。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Windows Forms`のリストビューには標準でコレクションバインディング機能はありません。

独自に実装する場合は[MSDNのサンプル](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/dd314007.aspx)などを参照するといいと思います。

Comment: やっぱりありませんでしたか。
ありがとうございます。
少し頑張ってみます。